# How to find covariance of two normal distributions

Tags: statistics

Suppose that $ X \tilde\ N(120,22^2)$ and $ Y\tilde\ N(2.5,0.6^2)$, how can I figure out the covariance of X and Y, or cov(X,Y). Is there a formula to do this or a software I can use to find the answer?

Comment: To find a covariance you have to know the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowledge of the marginal distributions is insufficient to uniquely determine the joint distribution, and consequently, the covariance or correlation between them.  For example, $X$ and $Y$ can be (trivially) independent normal variables with the means and variances you specified.  Or you could also have $$\frac{X - 120}{22} = \frac{Y - 2.5}{0.6},$$ or $$Y = \frac{3X - 85}{110},$$ and their correlation is now $\rho = 1$:  they are completely dependent, because knowledge of $X$ determines $Y$, and vice versa; yet they still each behave as normal distributions with the specified means and variances.